# In sed, can I prevent \S from matching parenthesis?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

The input file has this content

```
you have to identify (http://third-view.herokuapp.com/)
```

and I want to remove the URL, the desired output being

```
you have to identify ()
```

but the Sed command below also removes ')' parenthesis.

```sh
sed -i -e 's!http[s]\?://\S*!!g' file
```

Comment: Note that `\S` isn't guaranteed to work in `sed` at all; only POSIX-style character class specifications like `[[:space:]]` for `\s`, or `[^[:space:]]` for `\S` are portable to all standard-compliant implementations.

Comment: Simply `sed -i 's/http[^)]*//' file` will do.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, ...that's _if_ it'll always be in parens; if they could also have `you have to identify at http://whatever/ to continue`, then it's not sufficient. Up to the OP to know what the range of possibilities is.

Comment: Good point Charles. That was just thought No. 1 for the given string that came to mind while you were reworking your answer. I knew you would have a few nuggets to add to make it bullet-proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `()` to the list of characters you want to terminate on, by adding them to an explicit character class:

```
sed -r -i -e 's!http[s]?://[^[:space:]()]*!!g' file
```

Comment: You should probably mention that'll only work in GNU sed courtesy of `-r` to enable EREs and that specific `-i` syntax. If you change `-r` to `-E` then EREs will be enabled in GNU sed (except very old versions) and in OSX/BSD sed and if you get rid of the `-i` or change it to have a backup file name argument (optional for GNU but required for OSX/BSD sed) then the whole command will work in both seds. Also if you drop the -r, -E and -i args completely and change the `?` to `\{0,1\}` in the regexp then it'll work in any POSIX sed.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** Considering you want to neglect text inside `(..)` if yes then following may help you here.

```
awk 'match($0,/\(.*\)/){print substr($0,1,RSTART) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** In case you want to specifically substitute `http` or `https` value to just before `)` then following may also help you.

```
awk '{sub(/http[s]?[^)]*/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** `perl` solution with non-greedy matching, so in case you have multiple brackets `(....)` and you want to substitute value only in very 1st one then try following.

```
perl -pe 's/\(.*?\)/()/' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/([^)]*)/()/' file
```

Remove a starting paren and everything up to and including a closing paren with an opening and a  closing paren.